# Flask can't find template when specifying templates folder

Tags: python, flask

I created a template in the templates folder next to my Flask app. When I try to render this template, I get a 404 error in the browser. Why can't I render the template?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='/templates')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Comment: Remove the slash from `template_folder='/templates'`. It should look like `template_folder='templates'`.

Comment: Thanks for helping, all! No, its an 404 error. If you want, i can deliver screenshots as proof. I added the slash in the template_folder and the template_folder itself because of another topic i found here, when i already was searching for an answer.

Comment: Okay. Why can't flask find the template, even without the template_folder part or part edited as `template_folder='templates'`?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to specify a template folder for the app, it's automatically set to `'templates'`. As that default shows, it's a relative path.

You've provided an absolute path though, `/templates` is "the templates folder at the root of the filesystem". Your machine is unlikely to have a templates folder with your templates at the root.

Remove the `template_folder` parameter, or remove the leading `/`.